# apache_mod_loaded setting can fubar plugins?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache

I had a user recently who reported an issue with my plugin's options page not loading. They would click on the "settings" link but only got a blank page.

There was also an issue with the rich text editor showing up on the category edit screen.

I could not figure out why, on almost every other site but their's, the plugins loaded fine. We disabled all plugins except mine and still could not get the plugins to load properly.

Some time passed and I got an email from the user that he had resolved the issue (WP 3.1 site) by editing the file wp-admin/includes/misc.php

changing...

```
$got_rewrite = apache_mod_loaded('mod_rewrite', true);
```

To...

```
$got_rewrite = true;
```

Anyone have any insights into why the unedited file might cause issues with plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15044

> The problem appears to be localized
>   around the use of ob_get_clean in the
>   definition of apache_mod_loaded in the
>   branch that has to parse phpinfo.